# C# OnTriggerEnter, Pick up an object. OnTriggerExit, drop the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my sprite to pick up a cube when it encounters one, if it isn't already carrying one. If it is, drop the cube it is carrying.

This is what I have right now.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{      
    if (other.Tag == "cube")  
    {
        other.Transform.position = this.Transform.position;
    }
}
```

I tried telling the cube to become a child of the sprite. Wasn't working. All this does is put the cube to the sprites position when the trigger is entered, but the cube stays in that position while the sprite wonders off.

Comment: Unity? Add the tag please.

Answer (score 0):

With this code,you can change the cubes position to the players position just one time.If you want cube to move with your character than you should make child of your character.

Try using this code;

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{      
    if (other.tag == "cube")  
    {
        other.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    }
}
```

PS:I don't have access to Unity now.Some coding mistakes can occur.